# Render view from DB in MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

We are working on ASP.NET MVC 6 project and it's necessary to render Razor views from other than file system source (Azure Blob storage in particular but it's not important).
Earlier (in MVC 5) it was possible to create and register custom VirtualPathProvider which can take view content from DB or resource DLLs (for example).

It seems that approach has been changed in MVC 6. Does anybody know where to look for?

UPD:
Here is an example of code I'm looking for:

```
   public IActionResult Index()
    {

        ViewBag.Test = "Hello world!!!";
        string htmlContent = "<html><head><title>Test page</title><body>@ViewBag.Test</body></html>";

        return GetViewFromString(htmlContent);
    }
```

The question is: how to implement that `GetViewFromString` function?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this? I am looking for the same thing

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure a ViewLocationExpander:

```
services.SetupOptions<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
    var expander = new LanguageViewLocationExpander(
        context => context.HttpContext.Request.Query["language"]);
    options.ViewLocationExpanders.Insert(0, expander);
});
```

and here is the implementation for the LanguageViewLocationExpander :
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/ad8ab4b8fdb27494f5dece6f1186acea03f9dd52/test/WebSites/RazorWebSite/Services/LanguageViewLocationExpander.cs

Basing your `AzureBlobLocationExpander` on that one should put you in the right track.

Comment: It's not really what I was looking for (or at least I think so).

ViewLocationExpander allows you to specify some other than default folders where Razor Engine will look for view files. 

While I need something like the code mentioned above (see the updated question).

Comment: Now I understand. I'm sorry but I'm not sure how to make that happen. I was looking at the source code and doesn't look easy. One thing I can think of is to create a temporary .cshtml file but that's a hack and wont be very performant.

Answer (score -1):

Just posted a sample of store .cshtml in Azure Blob Storage to [GitHub](https://github.com/sbulluk/BlogSample-ASPNET5-ViewsInAzureStorage).

See also my answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281960/mvc6-load-razor-views-from-database/36924552#36924552) on this

Basically you need to create an implementation of IFileProvider. This can then be registered in Startup.cs by configuring RazorViewEngineOptions

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
    options.FileProvider = new AzureFileProvider(Configuration);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Alexei, I have put some detail in now too