# MVC6 Load razor views from database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

We are working on ASP.NET MVC 6 project and it's necessary to load and then compile Razor views from an external source (Azure document database).

I see in other SO posts (<= MVC 5) it was possible to create and register a custom VirtualPathProvider which can take view content from DB or resource DLLs (for example).

What are the options for MVC 6 ?

Comment: have you tried way provided for posts (>= MVC 5)  in MVC 6?

Comment: Thanks, VirtualPathProvider looks to not be available in mvc6

Answer (score 2):

Technically not implemented yet. This is after all a rewrite and not just a set of new features.

I found a [thread on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2432#issuecomment-95312850) which talk about a way to get what you need.

Basically, it's about providing your own implementation of [IFileProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/FileSystem/blob/1.0.0-rc1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.Abstractions/IFileProvider.cs).

I have virtually no experience in implementing this but I think that if you have time to spare, this is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but if you are still looking at this I have just posted a sample project to [GitHub](https://github.com/sbulluk/BlogSample-ASPNET5-ViewsInAzureStorage) showing how to store your .cshtml in Azure Blob storage using ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6.

@Maxime Rouiller - MVP is correct that you need to provide a custom IFileProvider. My sample is using rc1-final and working. Looking at the aspnet project though, this may change subtly later (will allow multiple providers to be registered)

A blog post write up on this should be coming in the next few days too.